# angular js filter/search and unique selects

Tags: angularjs, select, filtering

I've tried most of the SO answers for identifying unique values in angular.js ( i am a novice) but my problem is trying to get these into a select form and for that to have a filter on the data in a table.

essentially i have some data, I want to display it in a table and in the table header have a select dropdown of unique values in that column of data and be able to filter the table displayed by values selected.

I'm trying to use

```
app.filter('unique', function () {
return function ( collection, keyname) {
var output = [],
    keys = []
    found = [];

if (!keyname) {

    angular.forEach(collection, function (row) {
        var is_found = false;
        angular.forEach(found, function (foundRow) {

            if (foundRow == row) {
                is_found = true;                            
            }
        });

        if (is_found) { return; }
        found.push(row);
        output.push(row);

    });
}
else {

    angular.forEach(collection, function (row) {
        var item = row[keyname];
        if (item === null || item === undefined) return;
        if (keys.indexOf(item) === -1) {
            keys.push(item);
            output.push(row);
        }
    });
}

return output;
};
});
```

and my html looks like this

```
    <th> Number:        
    <br/>
     <select ng-model="search.number"  
             ng-options="row.numberfor row in data | unique:'number'">
    <option value=""> </option>
    </select>
    </th>
```

and then the table data itself

```
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="r in data | filter:{ number: search.number,  }">
        <td> {{r.number}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
```

The output generates this, but the value isn't set correctly so filtering returns nothing (as 0,1,2,3.. have not matching rows of data).

```
<select ng-model="search.number" 
ng-options="row.numberfor row in data | unique:'number'"  
class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
<option value="" class=""> </option>
<option value="0">1023 456789</option>
<option value="1">1024 456789</option>
<option value="2">1025 456789</option>
<option value="3">1023 111999</option>
<option value="4">1024 111999</option>
</select>
```

I've also tried this unique function

```
/*          
app.filter('unique', function() {
return function(input, key) {
    var unique = {};
    var uniqueList = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
        if(typeof unique[input[i][key]] == "undefined"){
            unique[input[i][key]] = "";
            uniqueList.push(input[i][key]);
        }
    }
    return uniqueList;
};
}); */
```

but no joy. i had to add `[key]` to this line `uniqueList.push(input[i][key]);` just to get the values displayed in the drop down, but I can't seem to control the values of the options in that drop down.

I have no errors in my console.

I have 10 columns/fields to filter on, but I've just included one example here.

Can someone help point me in the right direction. thanks

edit:

I see this directive might be useful, but when the map key->value are the same, is there a quicker/easier way?

```
app.directive('mySelect', [function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    template: '<select ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in myMap" ng-transclude></select>',
    link: function postLink(scope, element) {
      scope.myMap = {"1":"1","2":"2","3":"3"}; 
   // e.g. hashmap from server
    }
};
```

Comment: still struggling with this. the following is the output using the above method, the filter seems to work ok, but i can't see any of the values in the select options to know what to select `<th>field              <br>
              <select ng-model="search.field" ng-options="r.field for r in data | unique:'field' " class="ng-valid ng-dirty"><option value="" class=""></option><option value="0"></option><option value="1"></option><option value="2"></option><option value="3"></option></select>
             </th>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out this works

```
<select ng-model="search.<?php echo $column; ?>" 
        ng-options="v for (k, v) in data 
                | orderBy:'<?php echo $column;?>' 
                | unique:'<?php echo $column;?>' ">
        <option value="">select</option>
</select>
```

stuck within a foreach that looks at the each of columns in a CSV file.

i.e. the full excel style filtering with any csv passed in.